# How to check the realtime data transfer amount of my Tor relay

Tags: relays, routers, node

Recently I have set up a Tor relay, I can view the approximate data usage from the [Heartbeat] notifications, but as far as I know you can't manually activate it. As well, I'm SSHing to my server, and I can't interface with the already open terminal that is running the relay.

Is it possible to get a count of the amount of data that my relay has transferred over a certain amount of time? And a way to get the realtime transfer rate in kbps?

Any sort of help would get greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nyx - a command line monitor for tor https://www.torproject.org/projects/nyx.html.en